# Is it possible to have Visual Studio automatically swap brace styles?

Tags: visual-studio, coding-style

I find VS's default

```
if(foo)
{
    bar();
}
else
{
    fizzBuzz();
}
```

to be *incredibly* annoying. My personal preference is to have:

```
if(foo){
    bar();
}
else {
    fizzBuzz();
}
```

But some other developers either don't care, or prefer the default.

With version control tools like Hg and Git, you can do a "check out Windows style, check-in <strike>Gangam</strike>Unix style".

I was wondering if there was any way to make my Visual Studio open files with one brace style, and save them with another style?

Comment: It is something you can change for each language. What language are you using?

Comment: C# - I know I can change it for *me*, but that will make my code look different than other people, which is never good.

Comment: You can always write some macros or hook into the visual studio automation framework to do this for you. Not sure if this will be worth the effort for you.

Comment: @Oded do you know of any good resources for that?

Comment: I believe all of this is documented on MSDN, but I have not really done any such work myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will always be a matter of preference.
I think what you should do is get together with your developers, talk about it, and decide on one style to go with. Seeing as the other developers don't seem to care that much, chances are high that they will go with your preference.
What you should absolutely try to avoid is that one developer checks out the code, changes the style and checks it in again, only to have it changed back by the other developer.

**Also** : you can change your prefered style in *Resharper*, so that it will automatically layout to your preference.

```
ReSharper -> Options -> C# -> Formatting Style -> Braces Layout
```

Comment: Well, you beat me at yelling "resharper".

Comment: Agreed. Resharper is the way to go. But they also seem to have a lack of some minor coding style conventions. I believe it would really help for them to define those, and just live by them afterwards.

Comment: By the way, I personally prefer the VS default. I somehow want a bracket to have it's own line. I find it more readable.

Comment: I find the `{}` to be noise in the face of proper indentation - but then again my love is Python, so... ;)